# Android sdk 2.3.3 E/MediaPlayer(334): error (1, -2147483648) when Turkish chars used in setDataSource

Tags: android, media-player, error-code, turkish

In my program, I used url in mediaplayer's datasource. If url does not contain any turkish chars, it works normally. However, if it contains turkish chars, following error occurs:

E/MediaPlayer(334): error (1, -2147483648)

In the Url, turkish chars are used in the parameter part

Same error occurs when I use encoded Url, but same url is working correctly in mozilla

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of setting a URL as a datasource, I create a sound file (with HttpUrlConnection, I got the inputstream and wrote it in a file) and set it as datasource.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(URLEncoder.encode(yourSongURL,"UTF-8"));
```